# Why aren't arrays rented from a shared memory pool by default?

Tags: c#, .net

I've been perusing through the [high performance library offered by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/high-performance/introduction), specifically `MemoryOwner<T>`.

In the ['When should this be used?' section of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/high-performance/memoryowner#when-should-this-be-used) the following is said:

> A common use case is to replace new T[] array allocations, especially when doing repeated operations that either require a temporary buffer to work on, or that produce a buffer as a result.

Which implies that use of `MemoryOwner<T>` isn't exclusive to 'repeated operations', which I interpret to mean the initial overhead of renting an array from a shared memory pool VS allocation isn't a large concern.

A bit further down they offer an example where `new byte[]` is used in a function to read bytes from a stream, and the following is said

> If we read a large number of files, we'll end up allocating a lot of new arrays, which will put a lot of pressure over the garbage collector

The `new byte[]` is refactored to `MemoryOwner<byte>.Allocate()` as a solution to this problem.

My question is: If renting an array from a shared memory pool is more performant than allocation, and the initial overhead of renting isn't large, why does `new T[]` not rent from a shared memory pool by default?